# How to remove decimal in PHP?

Tags: php

I am currently echoing a number like this:

```
<?php echo $enterprise_platinum_price ?>
```

The problem is that the number normally has a decimal place such as `19.44` or `13.353`

I need to display the full number but without the decimal point or any of the numbers behind it.  I know that you can round to the full number in PHP but I don't ever want it to round up.  If the only way to do this is with rounding, I need it to always round down...

Comment: Have a look at str_replace();

Comment: ((int)$var) will cut the decimal point and all after that

Comment: `number_format` is valid as well for this

Comment: *intval($enterprise_platinum_price)* should do the trick too.

Comment: `current(explode('.',$enterprise_platinum_price))` - for the sake of adding more options to this comments list of answers

Answer (score 8):

Use the math `floor` function to round downward.

```
$a = floor(1.99); // $a = 1
```

You can also do it without rounding using `number_format`. There's many, many more ways, but I think the floor() option is the shortest for you.

```
$a = number_format(1505.99, 0, '', ''); // $a = 1505
```

Comment: `number_format($value, 0, '', '');`  would be more valid :)

Comment: @DarkBee Yeah, that would work well. I think in OP's case, floor() is more appropriate. But, I'll update with that code.